# Creating a Game Server

Tags: android, iphone

I'm interested in creating a server for an undetermined multiplayer game, either PC or mobile based. Any game server would obviously be event driven, asynchronous, and fast. I'm very experienced in web development, where it's common to use a framework such as Symfony for PHP or Django for Python.

Is there anything comparable to web frameworks for high performance game server development? ROS (Robot operating system) is an example of a complex C/C++ framework which is optimized for real time performance and includes common robot functionality. Is there something comparable designed for games?

Right now I'm most interested in creating a browser based WebGL game or an iPhone game. As such, I'm thinking of using Django as my request handler, and just doing communication over AJAX. I know that'd work nicely for a PC web game, but I'm not sure what the best ways of doing remote communication with an iPhone/other mobile device. Is it common to use a web framework to arbitrate mobile apps?

This is an open ended question, so any advice, thoughts, or links to further readings are much appreciated. If anyone has any good reading material I'd love to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it common to use a web framework to arbitrate mobile apps?

yes it is  take a  look at  webview (in android)

> Is there anything comparable to web frameworks for high performance game server development? ROS (Robot operating system) is an example of a complex C/C++ framework which is optimized for real time performance and includes common robot functionality. Is there something comparable designed for games?

you dont need a realtime system for this just a very good server (depends on  the amount of clients) in any case I would recommend  java.  It is  almost as fast (if not faster)  as  c++ applicators (thanks to jit)  and you can connect it to android easily (they are compatible) or use it as a classical web framework

Answer (score 1):

Since you have background in web development, you might be interested in the experimental Node.js/HTML5 game by mozilla http://browserquest.mozilla.org/

The source code is available here https://github.com/mozilla/browserquest

It's using websockets for client/server communications.

Answer (score 1):

It is defiantly possible to use a web framework.  A lot of this is dependent on the type of game.  The requirements are a lot different between words with friends, and Eliminator Pro.  But in general, for a lot of game designs a web framework/service model works great.

You could also look in to existing projects, such as [cocoas live](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CIYBEBYwAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/cocoslive/&ei=mCWkT-aKBO7k6QHlsvWeCQ&usg=AFQjCNEhGME1KbgVISIbghjxjBmRwqN85Q).